# Get div display table to have the typical dividing lines

Tags: html, css

this is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Nz9pY/14/

I'm trying to get the dividing lines between each column like I should have if it were a real table rather than a div with the table properties?

My research told me to add these lines but it doesnt do anything:

```
.table   { display: table; border-collapse: collapse;}
.tablerow  { display: table-row; border: 1px solid #000;}
.tablecell { display: table-cell; }
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9pY/16/?

Comment: Yes but it has double spacing on the inside

Comment: Sure- see: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Nz9pY/20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `border` to your css

```
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9pY/15/)

Update:

To remove the border on the last div, use the following instead:

```
#wrapper div:not(:last-child){      
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9pY/25/)

Comment: With that I end up with no border on the far left but one on the far right

Answer (score 2):

Adding that CSS wont work because you have no elements using those classes, you could simply add:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Nz9pY/18/)

`border: 1px solid #000;` 
to your CSS for 
`#wrapper div`

For no double internal; borders, use the below CSS:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Nz9pY/22/)

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: none;
}
#wrapper div:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#wrapper div:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
.lrg {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you do without double borders on the inside?

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
#wrapper div {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
#wrapper div:not(:first-child) {
   border-left: none; 
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9pY/23/)**

Comment: I dont see any border?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9pY/23/ here the solution for your request with thinner inner lines

Answer (score 1):

Give `border-left` to yout `div` elements inside your `#wrapper` element and also `border-right` to the `last` `div`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9pY/21/)

```
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-left:1px solid
}

#wrapper div:last-child{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-right:1px solid
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want all the borders to be visible

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9pY/24/)

```
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-left:1px solid;
    border-top:1px solid;
    border-bottom:1px solid    
}

#wrapper div:last-child{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-right:1px solid
}
```